# Click event on element with negative z-index

Tags: html, css

I have a parent element with partially transparent background. There is a child element inside of this element. And I need to show child element in the background of parent element, so I set z-index: -1 to child element.

Here is a codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpVbPa

The gray square is a child element. I need to handle click on it. How to do it? I tried to set `pointer events: none` on parent element, it does not work.

Comment: why you want to do like this?

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a pseudo element with a background and add `pointer-events: none` to it.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Chris-Happy/pen/MryweB?editors=0100#0)

```js
function childClick() {
  alert('click!');
}
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.parent:after {
  content: '';
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/fAYr5R/585e4ad1cb11b227491c3391.png);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.child {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" onclick="childClick()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: According to [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Browser_compatibility), it supports Safari 3 and up.

Comment: @RamzanChasygov, I think it might have been confused. See here: https://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Answer (score 1):

The principle in solving this type of problem is not having the background on the parent of `.child`, but on a sibling:

```js
function childClick() {
  alert('click!');
}
```

```css
.parent {
  position:relative;
}
.frontground {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/fAYr5R/585e4ad1cb11b227491c3391.png)
}
.child {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" onclick="childClick()"></div>
  <div class="frontground"></div>
</div>
```

In your case, the sibling can actually be a pseudo-element, but that might not always be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS. Set background to child's div `:after`

```
.child:after{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  content:"";
  z-index: -1;
}
.child {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```